# Using a runtime parameter (variable) in C++ metaprogramming at compile-time

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

Is there opportunity to make metaprogramming function but not expand all parameters in compilation? Just want to have some parameters as the runtime parameters and some compiles. Because I know that some of them will be in range of 1..10 but the other are unkown (will be known at runtime).

Lets use standard metaprogramming example:

```
unsigned int factorial(unsigned int n) {
    return n == 0 ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1); 
}
template <int n>
struct factorial {
    enum { value = n * factorial<n - 1>::value };
};

template <>
struct factorial<0> {
    enum { value = 1 };
};

// Usage examples:
// factorial<0>::value would yield 1;
// factorial<4>::value would yield 24.
```

And below is my case:

```
unsigned int cutom_imagined_function(unsigned int n, unsigned int runtime_param /* this will be given at runtime */) {
    return n == 0 ? 1 : (n + runtime_param) * cutom_imagined_function(n - 1); 
}
```

how can I convert above to metaprogramming? And run this let's say as below (or something similar):

```
// int variable;
// variable = get_var_from_user();
// cutom_imagined_function<4>::value(variable)
```

Comment: Your examples make no sense.  How am I supposed to describe how to implement `factorial<4>(variable)`, when factorial is a concept with only one parameter?

Comment: @MooingDuck That was only example... Edited. Better?

Comment: @awesomeyi Cannot? Why do you think I want compiler to determine runtime stuff?

Comment: @awesomeyi Sorry I don't get your point what is wrong with this title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the same approach: Constant expressions become template parameters, everything else doesn't:

```
template <unsigned int N>
struct cutom_imagined
{ 
    static unsigned int function(unsigned int r)
    {
        return (N + r) * cutom_imagined<N - 1>::function(r);
    }
};

template <>
struct cutom_imagined<0>
{ 
    static unsigned int function(unsigned int) { return 1; }
};
```

Usage:

```
unsigned int result = cutom_imagined<N>::function(get_input());
```

Comment: Here all the work gets done at run-time, right? Is this still meta -programming?

Comment: @unicorn2: Only the runtime work gets done at runtime. The compile-time stuff is done at compile time.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. In nosbor's example the result of the Factorial gets compiled as the resulting value. 
e.g. 
int y = Factorial<6>::value; looks like: int y = 720; in the .asm right?

Comment: @unicorn2: Same here - the function templates are created at compile time. So you have `cutom_imagined<6>::function(r) { return (6 + r) * ... }`, and there's separate code for each template specialization. (In fact, there may also be a lot of inlining, so that you never see the actual code per function, and only one unrolled function for your chosen `N`.)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you meant this:

```
unsigned int cutom_imagined_function(
    unsigned int n, 
    unsigned int runtime_param)
{
    return n == 0 ? 1 : (n+runtime_param)*custom_imagined_function(n-1, runtime_param); 
}
```

here's the general concept I think you're describing.  It's actually pretty straightforward.  Make the *function itself* a template.

```
template<unsigned int in>
unsigned int custom_imagined_function(unsigned int runtime_param) {
    return (n+runtime_param)*custom_imagined_function<n-1>(runtime_param); 
}
template<> 
unsigned int custom_imagined_function<0>(unsigned int runtime_param) {
    return 1; 
}

int main() {
    int variable;
    std::cin >> variable;
    unsigned int result = custom_imagined_function<4>(variable);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the slightly more verbose `std::integral_constant`.

```
unsigned int custom_imagined_function(
    std::integral_constant<unsigned int,0>,
    unsigned int runtime_param) 
{
    return 1; 
}
template<unsigned int in>
unsigned int custom_imagined_function(
    std::integral_constant<unsigned int,n>,
    unsigned int runtime_param) 
{
    std::integral_constant<unsigned int,n-1> less;
    return (n+runtime_param) * custom_imagined_function(less, runtime_param); 
}

int main() {
    std::integral_constant<unsigned int,4> four;
    int variable;
    std::cin >> variable;
    unsigned int result = custom_imagined_function(four, variable);
}
```

Additionally, now that we have `constexpr` (in some compilers anyway), the `factorial` is easily simplified:

```
constexpr unsigned int factorial(unsigned int n) {
    return n==0?1:n*factorial(n-1);
}
```

Comment: Ok that's a solution, but I suppose it will not be expanded as the orginal factorial. It's a simple template, not metaprogramming.

Comment: @nosbor: What do you mean by "expanding"?  You mean removing the recursion and taking advantage of the fact that `n` is known at compile time?  It already does, it just doesn't look like it.

Comment: Hmmm why are there no operators (`+`, `==`) for `std::integral_constant`?

Comment: @dyp: well that was silly of me wasn't it.  In C++11 it converts to `type` implicitly, which bypasses most places you'd want those operators. (Though VS is still lacking that part...)  You're 100% right that it'd be convenient though.  `template<class LT, LT LV, class RT, RT RV> std::integral_constant<decltype(LV+RV),LV+RV> operator+(std::integral_constant<LT,LV>,std::integral_constant<RT,RV>) {return {};}`